# Un-Frozen columns headers are not moving(scrolling) along with data when doing horizontal scroll in jqgrid particularly in IE11 and Chrome?

Tags: html, css, jqgrid, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

In `IE10`, the `un-frozen column headers` are getting scroll, when the data is `scrolled horizontally`. **IE 10**, there is **no Issue** and **working fine** as **expected**.

But in `IE11` and in `chrome latest version`, the `Un-Frozen columns headers` are not `moving(scrolling)` along with data, when doing `horizontal scroll` in `jqgrid`.

I set first two columns as `frozen to true`.

Code:

```
        $grid.jqGrid({
                        datatype: 'local',
                        data: myData,
                        colNames: ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4', 'Column5', 'Column6',
                                    'Column7', 'Column8', 'Column9', 'Column10', 'Column11', 'Column12'],
                        colModel: [
                            { name: 'col1', index: 'col1', frozen: true }, { name: 'col2', index: 'col2', frozen: true },
                            { name: 'col3', index: 'col3' }, { name: 'col4', index: 'col4' },
                            { name: 'col5', index: 'col5' }, { name: 'col6', index: 'col6' }, { name: 'col7', index: 'col7' },
                            { name: 'col8', index: 'col8' }, { name: 'col9', index: 'col9' }, { name: 'col10', index: 'col10' },
                            { name: 'col11', index: 'col11' }, { name: 'col12', index: 'col12' } 
                          ],
                        shrinkToFit: false,
                        rowNum: 20,
                        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
                        pager: '#pager',
                        gridview: true,
                        ignoreCase: true,
                        rownumbers: true,
                        sortname: 'col3',
                        viewrecords: true,
                        sortorder: 'desc',
                        caption: "TEST",
                        height:'auto'
                    });
            $grid.jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');
```

CSS

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0em;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: auto;
        text-align: left;
        height:650px !important;
    }
```

`Un-Frozen columns headers` are not `moving(scrolling)` along with data, when doing `horizontal scroll` in `jqgrid` particularly in `IE11` and `Chrome`. Provide me a solution. Thanks.

Comment: could you provide jsfiddle demo or another demo which reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add

```js
$grid.triggerHandler("jqGridAfterGridComplete");
```

directly after `$grid.jqGrid("setFrozenColumns");`. You should do this in case of filling jqGrid body *before* calling of `setFrozenColumns`. In my opinion it's problem of jqGrid (see the last post in [the thread](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/upgrade-from-4-5-0-to-4-5-2-breaks-sorting-fixed-column-grids)), which should be fixed, but Tony (the developer of jqGrid) have another opinion about the problem.

By the way I think that CSS which you use is not needed. Instead of that you should specify `width` option in the grid so that the grid will have horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: I tried using `$grid.triggerHandler("jqGridAfterGridComplete");` after `$grid.jqGrid("setFrozenColumns");`. Even though, the headers are not scrolling. Only the content can able to scroll. Thanks.

Comment: you should provide a demo which reproduce the problem. Th demo shoul d use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` of jqGrid 4.6.0 instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` to simplify debugging of the source code of jqGrid.

Comment: I found that due to some changes I had done in `ui.jqgrid.css`, the header scroll not properly work on..I once again get the `ui.jqgrid.css` from `http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.3.1/css/ui.jqgrid.css` and now it is working fine as expected. Thanks very much for your answer.

Comment: @JohnStephen: You are welcome! Is the problem is solved now? If you need to include `ui.jqgrid.css` you should load it better from CDN, http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css for example. You should never modify the original `ui.jqgrid.css`. Instead of that you can add after `ui.jqgrid.css` some other CSS rules which *overwrite* or extends the original jqGrid CSS rules. It will makes you easier to maintain you code and to usage of new version of jqGrid.

Comment: Yes, the problem has been solved. I will follow your advise when including `css` files. Thank You very much.